# Independence and ambiguity of holonomic constraints

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

I've got a couple of questions concerning constraint equations:

1. Suppose I've got $n$ holonomic constraint equations for a particle, how can I be sure those are all the ones there are and I didn't miss any? I mean, in a given situation, I can be pretty sure that I've got all, but is there a general rule about the number of constraint equations that are sufficient?
2. What does "independent holonomic constraints" mean? My book always insists they have to be independent. Does it simply mean none of them is a scalar multiple of the other?
3. Suppose I've got $n$ holonomic constraint equations that completely capture the constraint forces, are they unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not listing all constraints of a Lagrangian physical system might not be mathematically inconsistent, and may correspond to a different physical system, so indeed one has to be meticulous in writing down all constraints.
2. *Definition:* $m$ [holonomic constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) $$\vec{f}\equiv (f_1,\ldots,f_m):~M\times\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow~\mathbb{R}^m  $$ are *independent* if
   the [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(mathematics)) $d\vec{f}$ has maximal rank -- or equivalently, the $m$-form
   $$   \mathrm{d}f_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \mathrm{d}f_m$$
   does not vanish -- on the zero-locus
   $$ \bigcap_{\ell=1}^m\{f_{\ell}=0\}. $$
3. Constraints can be reparametrized, i.e. they are subjected to (possibly non-linear) transformations among themselves, and are therefore not unique.

   *Example:* $f_1$ can be reparametrized as $f_1(1+f^2_1)$.

Comment: I don't know differential forms; is there any intuitive elaboration on the 2nd condition? + does the third condition mean that I can non-linearly transform an equation of constraint into another one that represents the same physical constraint?

Comment: I updated the answer.